# Fill observable-fields-object by same fields-names object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have object that all of its fields are observable (knockout.observable).
I have other regular object too, that its fields have the same names like the first-object-fields.
I want to insert into each field of the first object, the value of the match-field at the second object.

For example:

```
    var first = {
        a:ko.observable(),
        b:ko.observable()
    };

   var second= {
        a:'my'
        b:'fields';
    };
```

I want the first object to look like:

```
   first = {
        a:ko.observable('my'),
        b:ko.observable('fields')
    };
```

**Yes, of course, I can do it by 'each' loop.**
**But, my question is:
Is there any build-in function that does it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ko.mapping` plugin:

```
var results = ko.mapping.fromJS(second, first);
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Did you make sure the `mapping` plugin is available at all?

Comment: May be, at the fiddle - it is not availabe. But in my project - It is available.

Comment: `ko.mapping.fromJS` itself doesn't change `first` data, it returns the merged results, which you should use as your view-model. Also, in older versions of Knockout, the mapping plugin may be available under `ko.utils.mapping`.